# Browser shows Website only on second call

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, internet

In a small company network, 1 Windows Server 2012 R2 and 5 Windows 10 Clients, the user experience the following problem. If you open a browser (same behaviour for Edge, Firefox, and Chrome) and enter a website you get an "page cannot be found error". If you type enter on the same address for a second time, the webpage shows.

The event logs don't show anything strange. I'm assuming that it is some kind of dns problem, but I don't know a way to dig deeper into the problem. Has anyone expirienced, or better yet, solved this problem?

Comment: What's your DNS forwarder setup?

Comment: There you go! It pointed to an old Domain Controller. I changed it to the address of the default gateway. thanks

Comment: Ok. I'll try to give more detailed information as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same problem with every browser, it's most likely a DNS recursion / forwarding timeout issue. The default [resolution timeouts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2834250/net-dns-forwarders-and-conditional-forwarders-resolution-timeouts) are

- `ForwardingTimeout` 3 seconds before trying the next forwarder
- `RecursionTimeout` 8 seconds before terminating the search.

If you have forwarders that doesn't work or a too long chain of forwarders, the querying client may timeout before your server gets response from its forwarders. The server continues and then caches the result, making it available immediately on the next time you try to access the page.